# Netbeans 6.9 / 7.0 Subversion Checkout Not Working?

Tags: svn, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-7

When exporting a netbeans project from an svn repository. It downloads everything in the respository to the folder I've specified in the default

> My Documents/NetBeansProjects

directory but it doesn't create the .svn folders for the project like it's supposed to. (It doesn't put the project under subversion control)

This has been drving me nuts because I can't seem to get any of my work under subversion control in Netbeans.

I'm running Windows 7 x64.

**EDIT:**

Here are the steps that I take to attempt to check-out a project from my servers repository so that I can work with it and keep it under version control in netbeans v6.9.

I go to:

> Team->Subversion->Checkout...

In the Checkout dialog box that appears I enter my repository's URL and my credentials then click the next button.

Once it connects to the repository I select the checkbox "Export a clean directory tree from the repository"

In the Local Folder input I specify the path where I want my project to be. "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProjectExample"

Then I click the Finish button and get the result I stated previously. When I was running netbeans 6.8, I believe I followed the same steps without any issue and NO, I'm not going switch back to 6.8

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: I have same problem on linux Ubuntu 12.04 and netBeans 7.2
It checkout my svn project, but he not creates files on project...
I don't understand how to work with SVN+netbeans .... >_>

Comment: If i want used svn+netbeans. I need to checkout my project, move with file explorer all svn files on netbean's project... !
Refresh project and thats works .... not user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just been getting the same problem, I think only on my Win 7 machine.  (Too lazy to test on Vista right now.)

I deleted the target directory manually and tried checking out **without** specifying "clean directory tree", and this time the .svn files were downloaded.

Comment: yeah that's actually what I did to get mine working aswell. Forgot to post my solution here. I guess the "export clean directory tree" means that you don't want the .svn files to be created

Answer (score 2):

Selecting 'Export a clean directory tree from the repository' when checking out the code from Subversion will check out the code without the .svn files and folders. Without those files and folders, your code will not be under source control. So try exporting but this time do not select the 'Export a clean directory tree from the repository' checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting in SVN means 'the content', but not the SVN structure. It is not the same as checking-out. If you check-out your project, you will see the .svn files.

**EDIT:**

To be more complete:

1. For a new project, you first need to create a check-out directory.
2. Then you need to check-out the project manually (with Tortoise SVN for example -> right-click on the folder etc...).
3. Then open your project in NetBeans.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing a checkout via netbeans. I'll edit / rephrase my question. @see the original post

Comment: Sometimes Windows hides .svn files, so may be they are there, but not displayed. I use Netbeans with Subversion and Windows 7 and I have no issue. I just perform the first check-out manually, then I can update, commit, etc... without issue from NetBeans. Did you actually try to check-out manually, then open with NetBeans?

Comment: @jVerstry I have my folder options set to show all hidden files and folders so I know that they aren't there. Plus Netbeans still says Import Into Repository under the Versioning context menu you get while right clicking on the project I supposedly just checked-out. I'll try checking it out manually via Tortoise SVN and then see if Netbeans can take it from there.

Comment: I did a checkout with Tortoise SVN into "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProjectExample" and that seemed ok, it also created the .svn folders in the project. I opened the project with Netbeans and it still doesn't think that it's under version control. The Subversion context menu when right clicking on the project is still replaced with the Versioning menu you get when Netbeans thinks your project isn't tied to a repository.

Comment: Eww... Others ideas: i) Did you make sure NetBeans installed all its latest updates? ii) Can you restart NetBeans if you did not? iii) Shutdown NetBeans, find C:\Users\<yourwinlogin>\.netbeans\6.9\var\cache and delete everything in it, restart NetBean, iv) Upgrade to NetBeans 7 and at last v) File a bug...

Comment: @JVerstry Clearing the cache seems to have worked for the project I checked out with Tortoise SVN. I can now commit changes and get updates. However, the built-in Subversion checkout in Netbeans still does not work properly. I downloaded and installed Netbeans 7. It has the exact same issue but I figured out that if I repeat the checkout process twice, both times exporting a clean directory tree, it seems to create the .svn files the second time around but then creates conflicts that are un-resolvable.

Comment: Edit: Although Tortoise SVN allowed the Subversion context menus to appear in my project, Netbeans still isn't keeping track of my changes. If I edit a file and save it, Netbeans doesn't inform me that that file has been modified locally.

Comment: Clearing the cache is sometimes necessary after NetBeans crashes or when it stops behaving properly for unknown reasons. For the build-in checkout issue, I'd log an issue with NetBeans and see what they have to say... May be put a reference to this thread.

Comment: I just ran the following test: i) I create a repository, ii) I checkout on a localdir1, iii) I open netbeans and create a project in localdir1, iv) I commit from netbeans, v) I close the project, vi) I delete localdir1, vii) I SVN checkout from NetBeans into localdir2 -> NetBeans detects the project, the .svn are there... , viii) I modify the project and commit from netbeans -> All is fine... I really don't know what is causing your issue... (I am on NB7)

Comment: @JVerstry I'll try to do the same thing and see what happens using Netbeans 7. Are you running the same OS?

Comment: I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it. I tried that simple test you did and still, it doesn't do the checkout once downloaded from the repository.

Comment: As crazy as it sounds, it could be. Bugs jump out from anywhere... If I were you, I'd contact the Netbeans team and submit this issue. May be you are the first one to uncover it. Give them a link to this conversion. There is nothing more we can do here...